# Redirect to login page if user is not logged in and the user want to access specific page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I want to redirect users to login page in Wordpress if the user has not logged in and want to access the following pages (blog, events, mentorship-forum, job-opportunities, internship, and volunteers). Currently, the redirect function is working correctly with the blog and event pages.

This is the function code:

```
add_action( 'template_redirect', function() {


    if ( ! is_page('login-to-view')  &&  ! is_user_logged_in() && ! is_page('/about-us') && ! is_page('/contacts') && ! is_page('') && ! is_page('/services')){
        auth_redirect();

    }

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if ( ! is_user_logged_in() && is_page( array( 'First page', 'Seconde page', 'Another page' ) ) ) {
    auth_redirect();
}
```

Do not forget to use the Page ID, title or slug.

Comment: Hey, it`s not working, the pages can be viewed even when the user is not logged in